# How to use QGIS plugin algorithm from R

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing

I'm trying to execute some processes from QGIS tools (3.16) from an script in R.

I can see the basic algorithms by calling this:

```
qgisprocess::qgis_algorithms()
```

I'm trying to use the `visibility:Viewshed` algorithm but It doesn't show in the list of available algorithms.

Comment: Is there a reason you repost your old question and then delete it?

Comment: This is an unique question, it could seems like this "Executing r.viewshed (GRASS) in R", but it is not the same at all.

Comment: I was talking about the question with the same context from earlier Dec. 20th 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling/disabling processing provider plugins has [become possible](https://r-spatial.github.io/qgisprocess/reference/qgis_enable_plugins.html) with {qgisprocess}, which is now on CRAN. `visibility` is one such supported provider.